# What is the better way to convert abrreviation language into full ( en -> English ) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make full language name from abbreviation.

I tried to make it using plain way (not working)

```
def long(lang)
 if lang == "en"
  lang == "English"
 elsif lang == "ru"
  lang == "Russian"
 end
 ...
end
```

What is better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you have a comparison operator when an assignment operator should be. Check this out:

```
def long(lang)
  if lang == "en"
    lang = "English"
  elsif lang == "ru"
    lang = "Russian"
  ...
  end

  lang
end
```

Or you can make it cleaner and shorter

```
def long lang
  map = {en: 'English',
    ru: 'Russian'}
  map[lang.to_sym]
end
```

Or even shorter (by eliminating temp variable)

```
def long lang
  {
    en: 'English',
    ru: 'Russian'
  }[lang.to_sym]
end
```

Comment: @Segio And when I will pass 'en' into method it will give me 'English' ?

Comment: Should do so, yes. Why don't you test that?

Comment: My code `if @website.language == "Auto"
      @website.language = long "request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first"`
What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`I18n` current locale, available locales etc are symbols, not strings. So you will have

```
def long(language)
  case language
  when :en
    "English (symbol)"
  when "en"
    "English (string)"
  else
    "something else"
  end
end

>> long(I18n.default_locale)
=> "English (symbol)"
```

If you want to do as you intended, you have to convert it to a string before.

```
def long(language)
  case language.to_s
  when :en
    "English (symbol)"
  when "en"
    "English (string)"
  else
    "something else"
  end
end

>> long(I18n.default_locale)
=> "English (string)"
```